# matplotlib.pyplot plot the wrong order of y-label

Tags: python, matplotlib, python-itertools

I tried to plot a bar figure and I want x-label to remain the specific order, so I use `set_xticklabels`. However, the result turns out the y-value didn't match the x-label.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
A=['Dog','Cat','Fish','Bird']
B=[26,39,10,20]
fig=plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)
ax1.bar(A, B)
ax1.set_xticklabels(A)
plt.title("Animals")
plt.show()
```

The expected result is `Dog=26` `Cat=39` `Fish=10` `Bird=20`, but the result I got is `Dog=20` `Cat=39` `Fish=26` `Bird=20`.

Here is one answer I found. However, if I use this method I cannot keep the original order I want.

```
import itertools
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt   
A=['Dog','Cat','Fish','Bird']
B=[26,39,10,20]
lists = sorted(itertools.izip(*[A, B]))
new_x, new_y = list(itertools.izip(*lists))
fig=plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)
ax1.bar(new_x, new_y )
ax1.set_xticklabels(new_x)
plt.title("Animals")
plt.show()
```

Is there any way I can keep the original order of x-label and make y value match with x?

Comment: Are you getting any compilation errors? I tried using PythonAnywhere to run this but I'm getting errors. Could be on my end though....

Comment: Yeah... I'm getting the following: `TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'float' objects`. Are you?

Comment: @LeviMuniz It worked fine on my computer. I'm not sure why it happened. Which one do you use, python2 or python3?

Comment: I'm using python2, I'll try 3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code will serve the purpose,

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

A=['Dog','Cat','Fish','Bird']
B=[26,39,10,20]

y_pos = np.arange(len(A))

plt.bar(y_pos, B)
plt.xticks(y_pos, A)
plt.title("Animals")
plt.show()
```

[image: click here to view output]

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you use pandas for storing your data:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib

A= ['Dog','Cat','Fish','Bird']
B= [26,39,10,20]
ser = pd.Series(index=A, values=B)

ax = ser.loc[A].plot(kind='bar', legend=False)
ax.set_ylabel("Value")
ax.set_xlabel("Animals")

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

In matplotlib 2.2 you can just plot those lists as they are and get the correct result.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
A=['Dog','Cat','Fish','Bird']
B=[26,39,10,20]

plt.bar(A, B)

plt.title("Animals")
plt.show()
```

[image]